# Uninstall windows and move all the left memory to Linux (Elementary OS)

Tags: linux, windows, elementaryos

I want to completely uninstall windows and merge the free memory left after to my Linux partition. What are the safest way to do this?

Comment: Delete the partition containing Windows and expand your current partition with the unallocated partition?

Comment: Do you mean disk space?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UEFI partition "system" need to be untouched. 
If you want to remove all Windows partitions anyway, better backup your data, remove all partitions and allow Elementary installer make all changes. That's fastest way.